# Tensorflow CNN Image Classification - Using ImageDataGenerator and then Next&Model.fit gives error

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN model, which is basically processing images and classifying them at the end. There are four class labels, which are UN, D1, D2 and D3. If you look at train_batches, you will see that it already labels them as an integer from 0 to 3. Before I send those images into CNN model, I been doing preprocessing. Those batches give me correct number of images and classes. However, when I'd like to plot them to see if I am doing anything wrong (using next function) or when I run model.fit_generator(x=train_batches, validation_data =valid_batches, epochs=5, verbose=2), it says "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 1".

I was suspecting there might be some "number of class" incompatibility but I could not figure it out.

[image: train_batches]
[image: ERROR]
[image: Train, Test and Validation files]
[image: what train file looks like]

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input).\
    flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(24, 1000),
                        classes=['UN', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3'], shuffle=True, batch_size=5)

test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input).\
    flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(24, 1000),
                        class_mode=None, shuffle=False, batch_size=1)

valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input).\
    flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path, color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(24, 1000),
                        classes=['UN', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3'], shuffle=True, batch_size=5)

assert train_batches.n == 240
assert test_batches.n == 40
assert valid_batches.n == 41
assert train_batches.num_classes == valid_batches.num_classes == test_batches.num_classes == 4

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
step_size_train = train_batches.n // train_batches.batch_size
step_size_valid = valid_batches.n // valid_batches.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_batches, steps_per_epoch=step_size_train, validation_data=valid_batches,
                    validation_steps=step_size_valid, epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` takes an input tensor with 3 channels, according to its [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input). You don't need this function since you're training your model from scratch. Passing rescale=1/255 in the ImageDataGenerator call will be fine for basic preprocessing.

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255).flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
                color_mode='grayscale', 
                target_size=(256,256),
                classes=['UN', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3'], 
                shuffle=True, 
                batch_size=5)
```

Also, as you are working with images, the input shape in the model will be the shape of the image. For example `(256,256,3)` and the target size will be `(256,256)`

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!